# How can I make my css :hover work?

Tags: css, hover

Bellow is my css i'm using. The div with the *largebutton* class on it works with the exception of the hover. I would like it to change it's background color, but am not sure why its not working. Any ideas?

**edit** - I'm working in FF at the moment. I'm not looking for support in IE6, possibly not IE7 either.

```
.top .bottombar .largebutton
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 195px;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.top .bottombar .largebutton:hover
{
    background-color: #9999FF;
}
```

**edit** - Full files

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="StyleSheet" href="css/LCARS.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="top">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
            <div class="leftbuttonbox">
                <div class="button">
                Label
                </div>
                <div class="largebutton">
                Label
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                Label
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottombar">
                <div class="button">
                Label
                </div>
                <div class="largebutton">
                Label
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                Label
                </div>
                <div class="label">
                    This is a label, it grows as large as it needs to
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cap">
                <div class="capinner">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "LCARS";
    src: url('../FONT/lcars.ttf');
}

body
{
    font-family: "LCARS";
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.top
{
    position: relative;
    height: 220px;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #6666FF;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 50px;
}

.top .content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 100px;
    bottom: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
}

.top .leftbuttonbox
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    bottom: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*
 * the button is 1/2 the size of the large button
 * the button box can hold 4 buttons or 2 large
 * buttons or any combination of equal size
 */
.top .leftbuttonbox .button
{
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
    width: 95px;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height: 53px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.top .leftbuttonbox .button:hover
{
    background-color: #9999FF;
}

.top .leftbuttonbox .largebutton
{
    position: relative;
    height: 75px;
    width: 95px;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height: 133px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.top .leftbuttonbox .largebutton:hover
{
    background-color: #9999FF;
}

.top .bottombar
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 200px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top .bottombar .button
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 95px;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.top .bottombar .button:hover
{
    background-color: #9999FF;
}

.top .bottombar .largebutton
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 195px;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.top:hover .bottombar:hover .largebutton:hover
{
    background-color: #9999FF;
}

.top .bottombar .label
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 50px;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: #CC99CC;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: default;
}

.top .cap
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 25px;
    width: 20px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: default;
}

.top .cap .capinner
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #6666FF;
    cursor: default;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50%;
}
```

Comment: On which browsers is this not working?

Comment: In IE6 `:hover` will only work on anchors

Comment: Well then in that case there's nothing wrong with that snippet. Your problem probably lies elsewhere.

Comment: Yi - Not sure where else it could be. I've attached the HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Justin: See: http://jsfiddle.net/4DZUH/. It works in a controlled environment. You must have left out something. You should also cut down on most of the selectors here, the styles are far too repetious, and you also need to define a font-family fallback in case the @font-face font fails to load

Comment: I looked at the link and the hover works. I'm not sure what I could have left out as there are only those 2 files. When I load it up in a safari they work, same if I use the webkit nightly. I'm not sure why they aren't in FF though.

Comment: @Justin Which version? I'm using 3.6 on Win 7, and it works for me.

Comment: You forgot to declare a DOCTYPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.top div.bottombar div.largebutton:hover
{
    background-color: #9999FF;
}
```

I think it's a bug in Firefox. Sometimes, when you add CSS for nested classes without specifying what elements these are applied to, the browser goes crazy. Your code works OK in other browsers, so technically it's not your fault, but FF's ;)

Comment: This works with my HTML as is. I also noticed I forgot a doctype. Adding it makes it work without this change.

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: Possibly FF quirks mode oddity then ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this solution:

```
.top .largebutton:hover
{
    background-color: #9999FF; /* make this whatever color it was before */
}
```

This worked for me when I tried it with your full code.
Hope it works for you :)

Amit

Answer (score 0):

The key concept of styling a link stands toward following steps:

1. You have to declare styles of 4 different condition which are `a:link` , `a:visited` , `a:hover` , `a:active` .
2. You have to be careful about the order. Because it matters. link > visited > hover > active. (especially to have :hover and :visited work...)
3. Eventhough you don't need styling one or more of conditions, nevertheless, style them all.

If you pay attention to these, you may have perfectly styled links.

I hope it helps.